# Filter rows of files conditional on multiple arrays values

Tags: arrays, loops, awk, conditional-statements

I have a number of files (N>1000) with qtl summary data e.g. lets assume the first file is made of six lines (in reality they are all GWAs/imputed files with >10M SNPs)

```
cat QTL.1.txt 
Chr Rs  BP  beta    se  pvalue
11  rs11224233  134945522   0.150216    0.736939    0.962375  
11  rs4616056   134945709   0.129518    0.371824    0.910326   
11  rs11823417  134945710   0.103462    0.41737 0.845826  
11  rs80294507  134945765   0.150336    0.735363    0.961403  
11  rs61907173  134946034   0.104531    0.158224    0.884548  
11  rs147621717 134946277   0.105365    0.196168    0.86476
```

I would like to filter each of these datasets based on chromosome and positions of a list of genes (my list has 100 genes but now lest assume it has 2); therefore creating N_QTL*N_Genes files. I would like to go through each gene/position for each QTL. The Chromosome, positions and name of the genes are stored in four arrays and I would like to read iteratively these arrays and save the output for each qtl file for each gene.

What I have done so far doesnt work and I know awk is not the best way to do this:

```
    declare -a array1    
    declare -a array2  
    declare -a array3  
    declare -a array4 

    array1=(11 11) #chromosome   
    array2=(134945709 134945765) #start gene position  
    array3=(134946034 134946277) #end gene position  
    array4=(A B) # gene name  


    for qtl in 1; do # in reality it would be for qtl in 1 1000 

         for ((i=0; i<${#array1[@]}; i++)); do  

        cat QTL.$qtl.txt | awk '$1=='array1[$i]' && $3>='array2[$i]' && 
        $3<='array3[$i]' {print$0}' >  Gene.${array4[$i]}_QTL.$qtl.txt; 
        done; 
    done
```

within awk $1 is the chromosome  and $3 the position- so therefore filtering based on these.

So my expected output for QTL.1.txt for Gene A would be

```
cat Gene.A_QTL.1.txt
Chr Rs  BP  beta    se  pvalue  
11  rs4616056   134945709   0.129518    0.371824    0.910326   
11  rs11823417  134945710   0.103462    0.41737 0.845826  
11  rs80294507  134945765   0.150336    0.735363    0.961403  
11  rs61907173  134946034   0.104531    0.158224    0.884548
```

And for QTL.1.txt for Gene B would be

```
cat Gene.B_QTL.1.txt
Chr Rs  BP  beta    se  pvalue
11  rs80294507  134945765   0.150336    0.735363    0.961403  
11  rs61907173  134946034   0.104531    0.158224    0.884548  
11  rs147621717 134946277   0.105365    0.196168    0.86476
```

I end up with empty files as probably the way I ask these columns to be filtered based on the values of the arrays doesnt work.

Any help very much appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post your input and output in CODE TAGS for better understanding of ours in order to guide you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. Is this any better?

Comment: Please add expected output too in your post too.

Comment: Should array2[$] be array2[$i]

Comment: Thank you, I edited array2 and added expected output too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do the following if multiple genes are located in the same chromosome (using gene name instead of chr as Key):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
        chr[$4]=$1;
        start[$4]=$2;
        end[$4]=$3;
     } 
     NR!=FNR{
        for (var in chr){
            name=var"_"FILENAME;
            if(chr[var]==$1 && start[var] <=$3 && end[var]>=$3){
                print $0 > name;
            }
        }
    }'  info QTL
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Mixing bash and awk for parsing files is not always the best way forward.

Here a solution with awk only.

Assume you have the information assigned to your bash array in a file:

```
$ cat info
11 134945765 154945765 Gene1
12 134945522 174945522 Gene2
```

You could use the following awk script to perform a lookup with the data file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
       for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
         a[$1,i]=$i
         next
     } 
     a[$1,2]<=$3 && a[$1,3]>=$3{
        print $0 > a[$1,4]"_QTL"
     }' info QTL.1.txt
```

This will create a file with the following content:

```
$ cat Gene1_QTL
11 rs80294507 134945765 0.150336 0.735363 0.961403
11 rs61907173 134946034 0.104531 0.158224 0.884548
11 rs147621717 134946277 0.105365 0.196168 0.86476
```

Maybe not exactly what you're looking at, but yet I hope this is helpful...

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I have a small issue with a[$1,4]"_QTL"- it doesnt like the "_QTL"  but works without it. However, I need to run this through a list of genes and for every QTL. Is it possible just using awk?

Comment: change "_QTL" with FILENAME.

Comment: Hi karafka, many thanks for the suggestion but I still get an error:                                   
 awk: syntax error at source line 7
 context is  print $0 > >>>  array[$1,4]FILENAME <<<                                                         awk: illegal statement at source line 8.                                                                     Sorry Im new to this and not sure what it means. Also my main problem is that I need this to run for all  rows and not just the first one.